# How to merge 2 numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I feel like there is some documentation I am missing, but I can't find anything on this specific example - everything is just about concatenating or stacking arrays.

I have array x and array y both of shape (2,3)

x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

y = [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

```
x = 1 2 3
    4 5 6

y = 7 8 9
    10 11 12
```

I want array z with shape (2,3,2) that looks like this

z = [[[1,7],[2,8],[3,9]],[[4,10],[5,11],[6,12]]]

```
z = [1,7] [2,8] [3,9]
    [4 10] [5 11] [6 12]
```

basically joins the x and y element at each position.

Comment: If you can look at the Python code for `stack` and `dstack`.  They expand the array dimensions and `concatenate` on one axis.  `stack` is new function in this family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the function you're looking for is `stack()`, using it to stack along the 3rd dimension.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
y = np.asarray([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
z = np.stack((x, y), 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have two-dimensional matrices, you can use [numpy.dstack()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
z = np.dstack((x, y))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [39]: z = np.concatenate((x[...,None], y[...,None]), axis=2)

In [40]: z
Out[40]: 
array([[[ 1,  7],
        [ 2,  8],
        [ 3,  9]],

       [[ 4, 10],
        [ 5, 11],
        [ 6, 12]]])
```